# Get value from sql select if parameter may be null

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ado.net, npgsql, executescalar

Looking for a method to get value of first row in first column from arbitary sql query in ASP.NET MVC Core application using EF Core.

Like

```
   var total = ctx.ExecuteScalar<decimal?>(@"select ... where p1={0}", null);
```

Tried https://github.com/weitzhandler code from  https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/969  with Npgsql EF Provider (changed to synchronous):

```
public partial class EevaContext : DbContext
{   
    public T ExecuteScalar<T>(string rawSql, params object[] parameters)
    {  
        var context = this;
        var conn = context.Database.GetDbConnection();
        using var command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = rawSql;
        if (parameters != null)
            foreach (var p in parameters)
                command.Parameters.Add(p ?? DbNull.Value);
        conn.Open();
        return (T)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
```

If parameter value is null line

```
command.Parameters.Add(p ?? DbNull.Value);
```

throws error

> InvalidCastException: The value "" is not of type "NpgsqlParameter"
> and cannot be used in this parameter collection.
> Npgsql.NpgsqlParameterCollection.Cast(object value)

Which is best way to run such query ?
Maybe EF core has some builtin method? Or is it better to use some type and inject it into EF Context is OnModelCreated method ?

If there is no better way how to fix this code so that parameters with null values are also accepted ?

There are lot of such queries with lot of parameters in application and re-qriting all of them in huge work. WebMatrix QueryValue was used in .NET 4 which allows null values in parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> command.Parameters.Add(p ?? DbNull.Value);

Is `p` an NpgsqlParameter, or some value that you want to send?? You cannot simply add values (or null) to `command.Parameters.Add` - you need to either wrap these with NpgsqlParameter or use `command.Parameters.AddWithValue()` instead. Note that the NpgsqlParameter also needs to have its `ParameterName` set correctly, correponding to the placeholders in your raw SQL (e.g. `@param1`).